# How do I expose some endpoints of the API Gateway to Beanstalk and others to the internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway with several endpoints currently exposed on the web. However, I want some of these endpoints to be accessible only by Beanstalk. At the same time, Beanstalk needs to expose some endpoints to the internet, so I believe I can't place it in a VPC.

My question is: Is there a way to securely expose certain endpoints to Beanstalk without requiring something like a token for access?

Comment: 'these endpoints to be accessible only by Beanstalk' - what do you mean? you mean *via* Beanstalk? I don't get it. You have publicly exposed endpoints on the web and then want to make them private for your Beanstalk application? What's the problem here and can you please provide an example?

Comment: Please share the diagram to describe your needs
[1. ]for the matter of "some of the API Gateway endpoints expected to be accessed by beanstalk only". Yes it can, you can set this up from the API Gateway side. [Check this out](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html#apigateway-private-api-create-using-console)

[2. ]it's highly recommended to secure your http request even it's only internal data exchange

Comment: Ah nevermind, we decided to use JWKS between services. With this, we can have a development environment making requests on other microservice